# how to get email id of the person which are in my contact list in Android

Tags: android

I just want to get email id of user having phone number given.
so i have to get email id of user whose number is like 986879899.so plz suggest me the solution of this problem or any links from where i got the solution.

I want to add one more thing that how to get person contact no. from my phone by referring  person name who is in my contact list.

Comment: Haha! you want to spy on your gf?

Comment: I do not think this is possible. A database of email id and phone number would be a huge privacy issue.

Comment: i got a solution, get a job in CIA or FBI or NSA, you'll be able to find out way more then just email id from that phone number.

Comment: hahaha no uDaY this is the requirement of my client :)

Comment: Directly give proposal to GMAIL and YAHOO..and Incorporating with them will solve this problem easily.

Comment: Mayank if i got the chance then may be i do more than that hahaha

Comment: you should just delete this question otherwise you'll just kill your reputation, just an advise

Comment: i want to know the email id of the persons which are in my contact list

Comment: well that's something different, go edit your question first and say this overthere

Comment: can anyone provide me an idea now ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    This is the solution of the above problem. Ashutosh given me the solution of the problem.


Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null); 
       while (emails.moveToNext()) { 
          // This would allow you get several email addresses 
          String emailAddress = emails.getString( 
          emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)); 
       System.out.println("email address might be"+emailAddress);
       } 
       emails.close();

        Thanks Ashutosh :)
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be something like this

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,  null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " = ?",  new String[]{"986879899"}, null);

cursor.moveToFirst();

cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup.Email));
```

you'll need to add permission to read contacts though